# Getting symbol related error despite pointing to Microsoft symbol server

Tags: debugging, windbg

Trying to debug a dump file in Windbg. Its a managed that interops with some Microsoft native libraries. I have setup symbol path to .sympath SRV*c:\SymbolsCash*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.

I loaded SOS without any problem. I can run sos commands without any error. I can also run most of the Windbg command fine (like ~, kb, .time etc), however for some command (e.g., !address -summary) I get following error.

> Your debugger is not using the correct symbols
>   In order for this command to work properly, your symbol path
>   must point to .pdb files that have full type information.
>
> Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not
>   contain the required information.  Contact the group that
>   provided you with these symbols if you need this command to
>   work.
>   Type referenced: ntdll!_NT_TIB

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your output, we can see you don't have symbols for ntdll. Note the line (3rd in the output above) that says you are using "export symbols". This means that you don't have the symbols for this module and the debugger is only using the entries from the module's export table. The structure you need is not included in the limited info that is the export table.

Your symbol path should look like:

```
SRV*<local symbol cache directory>*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

example:

```
SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

If you have your symbol path setup correctly, you can turn on verbose symbol loading by running:

```
!sym noisy
```

Then force a reload for ntdll.dll:

```
.reload /f ntdll.dll
```

Use the output to determine why you are not getting the symbol. Then
turn off verbose symbol loading by running:

```
!sym quiet
```

Also, I prefer the `!lmi <binary>` (e.g. `!lmi ntdll`) over `lmvm` when troubleshoot symbol loading. The output is a little clearer about what you have. At the end of the `!lmi` output you will see the line "Load report".

Comment: Thanks for your help. Any idea what does below mean? 0:000> .reload /f ntdll.dll
DBGHELP: .sympath srv*c:\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols\ntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: .sympath srv*c:\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols\dll\ntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: .sympath srv*c:\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols\symbols\dll\ntdll.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: ntdll.pdb - file not found

Comment: Seems like your symbol path is messed up there (note the missing http://), try ".symfix c:\websymbols;.reload" and see if that helps.

Comment: Actually it was a typo in my symbol path command :( Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

What does lmv mntdll say?

As the output says, it's possible that the type just isn't in that version of the public PDBs. It's not uncommon to find that debugger extensions don't work with specific versions of the O/S.

Comment: Scott, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Answer (score 0):

@snoone: Below is the output of lmv mntdll command
0:000> lmv mntdll
start    end        module name
76e40000 76f7c000   ntdll      (export symbols)       ntdll.dll
    Loaded symbol image file: ntdll.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
    Image name: ntdll.dll
    Timestamp:        Sat Nov 20 07:05:02 2010 (4CE7B96E)
    CheckSum:         001490D9
    ImageSize:        0013C000
    File version:     6.1.7601.17514
    Product version:  6.1.7601.17514
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Microsoft Corporation
    ProductName:      Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
    InternalName:     ntdll.dll
    OriginalFilename: ntdll.dll
    ProductVersion:   6.1.7601.17514
    FileVersion:      6.1.7601.17514 (win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
    FileDescription:  NT Layer DLL
    LegalCopyright:   © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.